# How can I wrap the table (CSS)

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Red: Window
Black: table

How to change the CSS make the green and blue div wrap the table?

*do not change the width of div

[image]

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/losiuhoi/xvV8E/

Comment: Live:  http://jsfiddle.net/losiuhoi/xvV8E/

Comment: Why are you setting a width on the table?

Comment: Because some column have long string, i must fixed the width of table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't specify the width of the wrapping divs (and put them `inline-block`):

```
.green{
    display: inline-block;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#0C0;
}
```

If you DO specify the width (like 98%) in your example, it won't wrap the table fully but only 98% of it.

Thanks to Paulie, here is a JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/xvV8E/5/

Also, `display: table;` would work as well, you have to chose which one is the most semantically correct i guess, if there is no other difference in behavior.

Comment: Very clean JSfiddle. Might I add it to the answer?

Comment: Absolutely, help yourself...`display:table` on the "green" div works too.

Comment: that's grate, but it will make the entering css "margin: 0 auto;" lose effectiveness. the div will float left